# Ext js - load combobox based on selection of 'parent' combo box

Tags: extjs

I am wondering if someone could help me with some probably rather simple code, whereas i have 2 related comboboxes. Upon selecting the first one, it will read the selection id of that combo and use that id to load the store of the second.
I'm just looking for a somewhat elegant solution to accomplish this.

thanks for any help!

fyi, i am using ext-js 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.extjs.com/learn/Tutorial:Linked_Combos_Tutorial_for_Ext_2

Comment: perfect , i'm surpirsed i didn't find this on the site when i was first looking . thank you!